# how to refresh the particular div while click image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I want to refresh div using image onclick. Here i have image,that image id's are 'sellhide',having the onemore div id's are 'sellChart'.
Code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 index_table_three" id="sellChart">
                        <div class="row" id="title">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6" id="">
                                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'lookup/be-check', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'id' => 'sellChartForm')) }}                                    
                                {{ Form::select('date_time', array($end_date.';'.$today => 'today', $lastWeek.';'.$today => 'Last 7 days', $lastMonth.';'.$today => 'One Month', '' => 'Custom Range'), $end_date.';'.$today, array('id' => 'date_time', 'onchange' => 'GetChangeDate()')) }}
                                {{ Form::Submit('Apply', array('id' => 'getSellRange', 'class' => 'getSellRange'))}}
                                {{ Form::close() }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="">
                                <h4>Sell property lists</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2" id="">
                                <img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH . '/mb-images/reset.png' ?>" width="35px;" height="35px;" class="img-responsive center-block" id="sellhide" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" id="sellDrawChart">
                            <h5 style="margin-right:70%;"><b>Property type</b></h5>
                            <canvas id="sellCanvas" ></canvas>
                            <h6 style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:80%;"><b>No of property count</b></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Script:

```
$(function() { 
      $( '#sellhide' ).on( 'click', function() { 
             $('#sellChart').html(); 
      }); 
 });
```

I have tried many ways its not accepted the script.

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Have you tried ajax call on click event and at response of ajax call change HTML hence div?

Comment: $('#sellChart').html();  will return only existing HTML.

Comment: @JaydeepPandya within a div i have some functionalities.above i have image, while clicking the image i want to reload the whole div ya

Comment: okay then you can try ajax call and on success replace HTML.

Comment: dis you tried like this? $('#sellChart').load(document.URL +  ' #sellChart');

Comment: @AshPatel in ajax i have tried $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo SITE_PATH.'/lookup/'; ?>",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#rentChart").html();
            } 
        });

Comment: This is wrong $("#rentChart").html(); you need to replace it with ajax data like => $("#rentChart").html(data);

Comment: @vel ya i tried its not working

Comment: @JaydeepPandya yes i used but not takened

Comment: 1. are you getting "data" exact what you want to show in HTML? and 2. where is "rentChart" in your HTML code, its not displayed here.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery get() method:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

For example:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```